# Can a past Expires header value cause a site to not be indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, http-headers, expires

I'm using this:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Will this cause my site to not be indexed by Google?

Answer (score 2):

Doing that won't get your sited banned or not indexed by Google, but you might rank better if you optimize for caching, for example browser caching setting expires headers far in the future for static files that don't change too often; Google takes into account how fast your pages are, because they encourage optimizing website speed for better user experience.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?csw=1) is where you can read about that in Google documentation.
[This](http://searchengineland.com/how-to-improve-crawl-efficiency-with-cache-control-headers-88824) is another helpful resource from search engine land.
And [some](http://moz.com/ugc/expires-headers-for-seo-why-you-should-think-twice-before-using-them) more about expires headers, from seo moz.